# How to get value from object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object list data like as

data:

```
[
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  }
]
```

I want to get name value from data.

code:

```
return(
        <Fragment>
            
            {Object.keys(cardData).map((keys)=>{
                <li>{cardData[keys].name}</li>
                
            })}
            
        </Fragment>
    )
```

but I don't get any data in return. When I use map to iterate it. An error shows me `cardData.map is not a function`. please help me for solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Couple of problems:

1. You need to explicitly add a `return` statement in the callback function of the `map()` method

   ```
   return <li>{cardData[keys].name}</li>
   ```
2. `cardData` seems to be an array. If that's the case, then no need to use `Object.keys(...)`. Call `map()` method directly on the array

   ```
   {cardData.map((obj) => {
      return <li>{obj.name}</li>      
   })}
   ```

   Alternate option is to remove the curly brackets. This will allow you to remove the `return` keyword and the `li` will be returned implicitly

   ```
   {cardData.map((obj) => <li>{obj.name}</li>)}
   ```

---

**Note:** Don't forget to add the `key` prop on the `li` element:

```
{cardData.map((obj) => (
   <li key={obj.id}>{obj.name}</li>
))}
```

---

#### Edit

If `cardData` is not an array, and is just an object of the following form:

```
{
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    ...
}
```

then use the following code:

```
{Object.keys(cardData).map(key => {
    return <li>{cardData[key].name}</li>      
})}
```

OR use the implicit return by removing the curly brackets:

```
{Object.keys(cardData).map(key => ( 
    <li>{cardData[key].name}</li>      
))}
```

Comment: `postId` is not unique, OP should use `id`

Comment: I can't use map because it is a object not array

Comment: @HR01M8055 yeah, didn't notice that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @MNTushar see the edit at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly `return` values from `map`.

Since `cardData` is already an array so you can use map directly on arrays, no need to take the keys and then process them to get the `name`.

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-haze-blve3?file=/src/App.js:726-849)

```
<>
  <ul>
    {cardData.map((o) => {
      return <li key={o.id}>{o.name}</li>;
    })}
  </ul>
</>
```

Comment: it is not an array. it is an objects

Comment: Arrays are objects in JS, and you can use `map` over it to iterate and `return` from them. `cardData` is an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Works like a charm !

```
export default function App() {
  var cardData = [
    {
      "postId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
      "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
      "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
    },
    {
      "postId": 1,
      "id": 2,
      "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
      "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
      "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {Object.keys(cardData).map((keys)=> {return <li>{cardData[keys].name}</li>})}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If `cardData` is an array, like in your code example, `Object.keys(...)` is not needed; `map()` method can be called directly on `cardData`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the return statement. In the documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) you can see they do it like this (They don't use a return statement inside the "{}", they simply use "()":

```
  return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(cardData).map((keys, index) => ( //Look here, they don't use any "{", hence no need for a "return()"-statement inside
        <li key={index}>{cardData[keys].name}</li>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```